# How do I keep a scheduled task running even though no user is logged in (Windows XP)?

Tags: windows-xp, login, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a temperature logger program and entered it as a scheduled task in Windows XP.

So far, I was able to achieve this objective:
1. Get the task to run even before anyone logs in (i.e. at the "Press Ctrl-Alt-Del" screen)

But I'm having problems with these:
1. When I log in, log out, then log back in, the scheduled task is no longer active. I can no longer see it in the Task Manager's Processes tab. I suspect it closes when I log out.
2. I tried to set the task's "Run As..." property to `DOMAIN\my-username` and also tried `SYSTEM`, but problem #1 above still persists.

**SUMMARY:**
I want my program to be running as long as Windows is active.

**EDIT 1:**
My program is actually a Python script. So its command line in Scheduled Tasks is:

```
C:\Python26\pythonw.exe "C:\path\to\templogger.py"
```

It writes data to a file in local public folder (e.g. fully accessible by all who login locally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach for this is to run it as a service. You can probably get away with it just by using [Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Comment: To add to this: yes, I would write it as a service, but I would also still use scheduled tasks to simply control starting or stopping the service.

Comment: Can I avoid writing it as a service? I don't know anything about writing programs as Windows services. My program is a Python script. See __EDIT 1__ above.

Comment: Its pretty easy to do. First you need srvany.exe which comes with windows resource kit. Second, either use freeware or command line to create the service. Then add to the registry for that service. Ive had to do this to run python scripts headphones, sickbeard or ouchpotato as windows services.

Comment: NSSM (http://nssm.cc/) is better than srvany.exe.  I have used to it run a python script as a service with no issues, just make sure your paths are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried giving the user "log on as a batch job" and "log on as a service" rights ?

Comment: ntrights.exe from the resource kit can give an account this privilege if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Instead of phrasing this as a question, you should phrase it more as an answer ;)